# Formula to compare value with 2 options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a list of Joomla websites that I maintain in Excel, and one of the fields contains the site's current Joomla version. I also have two fields where I put the version number of the latest oficial Joomla versions (currently 2.5.19 and 3.2.3).
Is it possible to create a formula that changes the text based on update status (e.g. green for 2.5.19 OR 3.2.3, and red for any other value)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest Conditional Formatting. Select your range and format all of it red (to save one CF rule) then apply something like below:

[image: SO22952178 example]

where the formula in full is:

```
=OR($B3=$A$9,$B3=$A$10)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. Formatting everything red as default really makes things easier, I can't believe I didn't think of that...